# Error migrating O365 mailbox back to on-prem

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I am trying to migrate a O365 mailbox to on-prem.  When I checked for the GUID on the exchange server as the prereq indicates, there was a number that wasn't all zeros, so I assuming this mailbox was originally on-prem, then migrated to O365.  When I run the migration, it gives the following:

12/13/2016 9:26:17 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Stage: CreatingFolderHierarchy. Percent complete: 10.
12/13/2016 9:26:18 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Initializing folder hierarchy from mailbox 'company.onmicrosoft.com\cdf0af81-db6b-43ed-aad4-27eeef847073 (Primary)': 136 folders total.
12/13/2016 9:26:18 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Folder creation progress: 0 folders created in mailbox 'company.onmicrosoft.com\cdf0af81-db6b-43ed-aad4-27eeef847073 (Primary)'.
12/13/2016 9:28:33 PM [BLUPR05MB936] **Transient error CommunicationErrorTransientException has occurred. The system will retry (3/600).**
12/13/2016 9:29:04 PM [BLUPR05MB936] The Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service 'BLUPR05MB936.namprd05.prod.outlook.com' (15.1.789.9 caps:07FFFF) is examining the request.
12/13/2016 9:29:06 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Connected to target mailbox 'company.onmicrosoft.com\cdf0af81-db6b-43ed-aad4-27eeef847073 (Primary)', database 'db1_1', Mailbox server 'mail1.corp.company.com' Version 14.3 (Build 319.0), proxy server 'mail1.corp.company.com' 14.3.227.0 caps:05FFFF.
12/13/2016 9:29:06 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Connected to source mailbox 'company.onmicrosoft.com\cdf0af81-db6b-43ed-aad4-27eeef847073 (Primary)', database 'NAMPR05DG059-db021', Mailbox server 'BLUPR05MB936.namprd05.prod.outlook.com' Version 15.1 (Build 789.0).
12/13/2016 9:29:08 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Request processing continued, stage CreatingFolderHierarchy.
12/13/2016 9:29:08 PM [BLUPR05MB936] Stage: CreatingFolderHierarchy. Percent complete: 10.

We have 2 exchange servers in a DAG.  I tried stopping the sync, and making the DB on the other server the active one, and resuming the sync.  I was thinking that the server has switched during the migration.  That didn't work.  I also tried deleting the migration job and trying again using a different DB.  I wasn't able to find much on the internet regarding this.  I have migrated several mailboxes, so I know the process works.  Just this mailbox is giving me grief.  Any thoughts?

Edit: One thing that hasn't made a difference, was the mailbox wasn't licensed.  I assigned it a license and tried to migrate it, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize as this "answer" might not seem complete enough, as a co-worker ended up figuring it out, and quickly explained it to me.  I'm still trying to figure out all the parts to it, so I complete understand what he did.

Apparently, this has happened a couple times in the past with these users from another country.  As they are on Exch 2003, and the rest of the company is on 2010 and 2013.  They got migrated to O365, then back to on-prem recently.  My co-worker used `Get-MoveRequest` to find the user, and then piped in `Get-MoveRequestStatistics` for the user, which gave quite a lot more detail about the process, rather than the log in the O365 tool.  This pointed to the fact that mailbox didn't have any search folders, so when the migration process was trying to build them, it couldn't find them online, and therefore stalled at 10%.

To resolve it, my co-worked had to change the password on the user's mailbox, log in to create a new profile using a laptop, and delete those search folders.  He then created a new migration sync and it worked.  Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

He also pointed out an attribute msExchMailboxMoveStatus (I think that is the one) which is used as a flag showing the mailbox in move status (icon for little green arrow).  This flag got set during the attempts to migrate and wouldn't come off, so you might have to clear that before trying a new migration.